# Do Americans want to abolish the two-party system? If no, why not? If yes, why do they take actions that only strengthen it?

Tags: united-states, democracy, parties, political-system

Most countries have figured out that a two-party system is pretty inefficient. One could write a book or two about why this is so, but suffice it to say that a two-party system is too coarse to properly represent an entire political spectrum.

My question is twofold.

Firstly, I understand that some Americans realise this, and do want more parties. But many also do not want more parties. Here is one poll showing that there's maybe an equal number of people on both sides:

https://edition.cnn.com/2019/03/04/politics/two-party-system-poll/index.html.

So I will ask a question for each group.

1. To the people who do not want more parties, my question is simply ... why not? What arguments do these people offer?
2. To the people who do want more parties, my question is, why do even these people tend to take actions that help solidify the two-party system? Here, I am specifically referring to the notion of being "a conservative" or "a liberal". I've never spoken politics to an American without them using these terms to label themselves. Nobody does this in my country. Surely putting your entire political belief system into one of two boxes and labeling it like that, only helps strengthen the notion that there **are** only two systems and therefore two parties are the only ones needed to represent them? Obviously there's a "chicken or egg" thing going on here. Maybe these terms exist precisely because they are natural to use given that you live under a two-party system. But perhaps the two-party system exists because Americans really do think in such binary terms to begin with.

Comment: There is another possibility not considered in the question: people who think a system with multiple parties would be preferable but nonetheless label themselves as "conservative" or "liberal."

Comment: Simply put the way the electoral college is set up pretty much takes away the people's vote if there are ever 3 or more competitive candidates as if someone doesn't get 50% + 1 of the vote congress decides the winner from the top 3. Because of this there is a strong incentive to limit it to two parties.

Comment: Most people who want more parties understand that unless a third party gets significant *countrywide* traction, the only thing they'll accomplish by voting their third party locally is to increase the odds of the party they favour the *least* winning. Basically, they support the two party system because it's the only game in town. And neither party will fracture because then the other party will have an effective majority as long as it doesn't fracture.

Comment: As an example of what @Shadur wrote, the third party candidacy of Theodore Roosevelt in the 1912 Presidential Election almost certainly resulted in Woodrow Wilson winning that election. Without ranked choice voting, the US is pretty much stuck with a two party system.

Comment: @JoeW Re *if someone doesn't get 50% + 1 of the vote congress decides the winner*. That's not necessarily the case. George Wallace's goal in the 1968 election was to win enough electoral votes to keep both Nixon and Humphrey below 50% of the electoral vote. That would have allowed Wallace to play kingmaker. His plan was to direct the electors he had won to vote for Nixon or Humphrey, based on concessions made to Wallace.

Comment: *two-party system is too coarse to properly represent an entire political spectrum*  That's quite the claim, and I'll counter it with some examples:  Israel and its perennial mess where small parties can play kingmaker.  France, where no matter how many parties are in round #1, only the top 2 go to run offs:  the last election came within a hair's breadth of saddling voters with either extreme right (LePen) or extreme left (Melenchon) choices.  What makes the US inherently worse than those 2 cases?

Comment: @DavidHammen That still would have resulted in someone getting 50% +1 of the electoral college vote and that is an edge case. My point was if you had a 3 way race where it ended up being 45%, 40%, 15% the final decision would got to congress and it would be within the law for them to choose the 3rd place person with only 15% of the vote.

Comment: @ItalianPhilosophers4Monica I think it’s hard to argue that the 2-party system isn’t too coarse a tool, but as you say, it’s not clear that other systems are better

Comment: There are 328 million people in America. They don't all agree on much, especially politics. This question isn't answerable.

Comment: @JoeW if there's an odd number of electoral votes, the threshold is 50%+0.5.  It's simpler just to say "a majority."  It's fewer syllables, too.

Comment: Why is this question closed? It is obviously about politics, and any potential answer would seem very useful, as evident by the comments here. Can this be reopened please?

Comment: @user000001 Because it is asking for guesses about if Americans want to abolish the two party system which would be pure speculation.

Comment: @JoeW: Surely somebody has done some kind of statistical analysis of this question...

Comment: @user000001 But the question is asking if they want a third party why do they strengthen a two party system. Answering that question is going to take a lot more than simple stats.

Comment: @user000001: It's a really bad question, as currently phrased, because it assumes that "Americans" can have one single opinion on the question.  Quite obviously many Americans want more than two parties, because they support parties like the Libertarian, Green, American Independent, and others.  Just as obviously many don't, because they have vested interests in the current system.  And it's a good bet that the majority don't really care one way or the other.

Comment: Questions on polling data are fairly common here, don't know why this was closed

Comment: @KDog - I'd guess because it also includes a "Why do people do this?" question, rather than just being about the polling.